# How to render a form with multiple records without additional schema

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I need to create a form where a user can edit multiple records of Paper at the same time. Right now I'm using an embedded schema so Ecto can do the casting for me:

```
defmodule EmbSchema do
  embedded_schema do
    has_many :papers, Paper
  end

  def changeset(emb_schema, attrs) do
    emb_schema
    |> cast(attrs, [])
    |> cast_assoc(:papers, with: &Paper.classify_changeset/2)
  end
```

and the default HTML helpers to render the form

```
<%= inputs_for f, :papers, fn p -> %>
```

The only problem is that I get a warning

```
invalid association `papers` in schema EmbSchema: associated schema Paper does not have field `emb_schema_id`
```

which is of course correct, but doesn't matter for my usecase.

Since this feels a bit like a hack, is there some other way to model this?

Comment: I would say, `Ecto` hints that for this particular case you might better use [`Ecto.Schema.embeds_many/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embeds_many/3). `embedded_schema` without a back reference is a clear design flaw.

Comment: Thanks, embeds_many seems like a way to go. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Put
@primary_key false

above embedded_schema